# Напомните, как называются суффиксы в выражениях, такие как ll, f? C++

Tags: c++, литерал

В выражениях можно указать тип литерала, например 1ll - это число 1 типа long long int, 1.f - число 1 типа float и тд. Как называется эта фича? И если у кого-то будет ссылка на табличку со всеми подобными суффиксами, скажу отдельное спасибо. Точно помню, что этих суффиксов гораздо больше, чем 2, но никак найти не могу для изучения

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions

Comment: @user7860670, и где в этой портянке нормальный человек найдет ответ на свой вопрос?

Comment: @user7860670 действительно сложно в этой каше что-то найти

Comment: @ComeInRage ¿Вы точно дочитали станицу до конца?

Comment: @user7860670 да. И только спустя минут 10 нашел выкладку о литералах. В любом случае лучше, чем ничего, так что все равно спасибо

Comment: [integer literals](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.literal#lex.icon-3), [character literals](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.literal#lex.ccon-2), [floating point literals](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.literal#lex.fcon-1).

Comment: @ComeInRage, собственно, они так и называются -- **суффиксы** (unsigned-suffix, long-suffix, long-long-suffix, size-suffix, floating-point-suffix и ud-suffix для *User-defined literals*)